# What are implications of namespacing classes under same namespace/under the same name as a module

Tags: ruby, class, module, namespaces

As in the title. I have this:

```
module Car
 # stuff here
end

class Car::SUV
  #stuff here
end

class Car::Hatchback
  #stuff here
end
```

Are there any implications at all to the fact that my classes are namespaced with my module's name? What about the fact that they are namespaced under the same name? As far as I understand no variables are shared here, and the only reason to namespace classes is to avoid name clashes?

Thanks.

Comment: You are right, namespacing is _just_ about namespacing and doesn't give you the same behavior as inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, namespacing as described in the question is just namespacing, and so the above are completely separate modules/classes.